# Properly mark up multiple person using schema.org microdata

Tags: html5, microdata

I am creating a radio episode that will have multiple conductors (usually 1 to 3):
 inside a loop I am associating those conductors to `director` providing also the `url` linking to their respective *conductors* page:

```
<h3 class="conductors">
    Conducted by

    start loop...

    <span itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">
            <a href="{{url}}" itemprop="url">{{name}}}</a>
        </span>
        <meta itemprop="jobTitle" content="Conductor">
    </span>

    end loop....

</h3>
```

but I am not sure if I am doing it well and I feel I could have done multiple mistakes:

- The way I define the multiple `person`
- How I am associating the `url`
- The jobTitle (I expect this to better specify the `director` in some way)
- span inside span (trying to have conductors on one line and inside an heading for better semantically specify that they important to the radio episode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Microdata / Schema.org

Your use of Microdata and the Schema.org vocabulary is fine.

To specify multiple directors, you have to provide multiple `director` properties, which your loop seems to achieve:

```html
<span itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</span>
<span itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</span>
<span itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</span>
```

To specify a URL value, you have to use a suitable link element (with `href` or `src` attribute), like `a`, `link`, `img` etc. So your use of the `a` element achieves this.

I prefer using `http` Schema.org URIs ([reasons why](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68741/17633)), but using `https` is fine, too.

#### HTML

Is this `h3` really the heading for a section of content? If yes, your markup is fine. But then you might want to add a textual delimiter (like `,`) to separate the conductor names.

If the section should just specify the conductors, and there is no other content under its scope, the `h3` should just be something like "Conducted by", with the list of conductors under its scope:

```html
<h3>Conducted by</h3>

<ul>
  <li itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</li>
  <li itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</li>
  <li itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">…</li>
</ul>
```

Headings should not be used for content just because this content is important. [`h1`-`h6`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) don’t represent important content, they represent "headings for their sections". There is typically no case where you should have a heading without any content in its section.